# LibreOffice on Windows 11 - no light mode

Tags: windows-11, libreoffice

I just installed LibreOffice 7.5.0.3, and out of the box, it looks very unpleasant - everything is black and high contrast.

[image: screenshot]

I don't think it is supposed to look like this. I've tried changing **Tools > Options > Personalization**. But that only changes the toolbar colors, causing it to look even worse with unreadable icons, not to mention the black background is still there.

[image: screenshot2]

I think changing my Windows theme might possibly help, but I'd rather not. Can I tell LibreOffice to ignore the Windows theme?

How can I make it light?

Comment: I think (I am not certain) that Libre Office uses the HOST OS theme. I have Libre Office 7.3 on my Ubuntu machine (ligtt mode) and Libre Office is light mode as well. So I think you may need to change your Windows theme to accommodate. Or, use a different Office Suite?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-change-themes/4764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now with version 7.5.0.3, you can't set theme to light mode from LibreOffice. The issue was reported to LibreOffice developers. You can follow the bug tracker [here](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=153229). This version of LibreOffice is following the OS/system theme.

They (the developers) have a solution that will allow the user to select either Light, Dark or System mode. It will be backported to in the coming days to versions 7.5.1 and 7.5.2. It will also be present in version 7.6. You can check the [daily builds](https://dev-builds.libreoffice.org/daily/) and test if it is solved (according to comments on the bug tracker page, it is solved).

**UPDATE**

The problem has been solved in version 7.5.1.2. Go to Tools -> Options -> View. Set the Mode to Light.

[image: Appearance options]