# Windows 10 forces dark mode on Libre Office

Tags: windows-10, libreoffice, themes, dark-mode

Starting from the latest version of LibreOffice (7.5.2.2) I'm having a problem, which is that the interface appears as follows:

[image]

I thought that LibreOffice now came pre-installed with the dark theme, so I checked the settings. Though, that appears not to be the case:

[image]

[image]

I then made some experiments and discovered that if I deactivate Windows 10's dark mode everything reverts back to normal:

[image]

I can set the dark mode so that it doesn't ovveride the apps as well, but if I do so parts of Windows's interface remain white, so that's not good:

[image]

Until version 7.4 everything was fine: Windows in dark mode, app in default mode. Is there a way I can set it back this way?

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, resetting the user profile, installing from a different source (scoop) and none of that worked.

Comment: Windows does not force apps to do anything like that. It cannot. If you think this behavior in LibreOffice is incorrect, only LibreOffice is at fault.

Comment: Libre Office on my Ubuntu System (Light) is Light. So it is a Libre Office issue rather than Windows

Comment: Check my answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1768724/libreoffice-on-windows-11-no-light-mode/1768903#1768903). Does it answer your question?

Comment: Ehy, it does! Great